# Don't see the Microsoft.Jet provider in my new SQL Server 2008 R2 instance?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I moved an Excel linked server from SQL Server 2005 (it was built on Jet 4.0, excel 5?) to a new SQL Server 2008 R2 instance (64 bit environment). I matched the settings for both, but it seems the system tables in the Catalogs\defaults.. didn't transfer..

The new server providers list doesn't have the Jet 4 or the Microsoft ACE 12....

How can I install them? hoping that will fix the issue

Thanks in advance,

Shayma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that starting in 2008 R2 Jet was no longer included with the SQL Server install.  For R2 64 bit I believe you will need to download and install the Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable package found [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).

This should install the necessary drivers for Office doc access from 64 bit SQL Server.

Comment: You are right, I downloaded it and fixed the problem. Thank you so much.